# RegEX 14 digits validation with dash separator

Tags: javascript, java, regex, validation

I'm using the following regex `^[\d]{4}[-]?[\d]{6}[-]?[\d]{4}$` 
to validate 14 numbers as a **whole** or divided as

```
4 digits - 6 digits - 4 digits
```

the following four examples are matching my regex but i want to exclude the last two example.

- `1111-111111-1111` - (valid according to my business logic)
- `12341234561234` - (valid according to my business logic)
- `1111-111111111` - (I want this to be not valid)
- `1111111111-1111` - (I want this to be not valid)

Comment: so do an or....

Comment: Do you want this answer with Java or JavaScript.... issue is JavaScript does not support everything that Java does with regular expressions.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do a negative look ahead for patterns you don't want to match and use this regex,

```
^(?!\d{4}-\d{10})(?!\d{10}-\d{4})\d{4}-?\d{6}-?\d{4}$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` --> Start of string
- `(?!\d{4}-\d{10})` --> Negative lookahead to avoid matching this pattern
- `(?!\d{10}-\d{4})` --> Negative lookahead to avoid matching this pattern
- `\d{4}-?\d{6}-?\d{4}` --> Matches the pattern as you wanted
- `$` --> End of string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2olqrZ/1)

Another pattern I could think of, is more simple and elegant, you can use is this,

```
^\d{4}(-?)\d{6}\1\d{4}$
```

**Explanation:**

- `^` --> Start of string
- `\d{4}` --> Matches exactly four digits
- `(-?)` --> Matches an optional hyphen and captures in group 1
- `\d{6}` --> Matches exactly six digits
- `\1` --> This ensures that both hyphens are either present or are absent as mentioned in the regex
- `\d{4}` --> Matches exactly four digits
- `$` --> End of string

[Demo](https://regex101.com/r/2olqrZ/2)

Answer (score 2):

Just use an or with the pattern or 14 numbers.

```js
var re = /^(\d{4}-\d{6}-\d{4}|\d{14})$/

function test(str) {
  console.log(str, re.test(str))
}

['1234-123456-1234', '12341234561234',
'1234-1234561234', '1234123456-1234'].forEach(test)
```

Answer (score 0):

^([\d]{4}[-]?[\d]{6}[-]?[\d]{4})|([\d]{16})$

Hope this helps!
it has two regex one with hiphens another with whole number(16 digits)